# Jquery validate submitHandler is not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with two buttons

a) Test  - on click of the button a javascript function is called to verify a couple of credentials.

b) Create - on click of the button a javascript function is called to save the form.
 @Messages("playauthenticate.project.create")

I have a form tag around these two submit buttons with no action.

name, description, accessKey and secretKey are the four fields in the form.

on clicking on the create button, I want to perform jquery validation and then submit the form but the jquery validation submitHandler is not getting called in the javascript function and there are no errors in the Error Console.

When I click on the create button, the create alert is shown and then the form resets and I am able to see all the parameters entered in the URL.

```
$("create").click(function() {

        alert("create ");

        $('#projectForm').validate( { 
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        minlength: 6,
                        required: true
                    },
                    description: {
                        required: true,
                        description: true
                    },
                    accessKey: {
                        minlength: 10,
                        required: true
                    },
                    secretKey: {
                        minlength: 15,
                        required: true
                    }
                  },
                  focusCleanup: false,

                wrapper: 'div',
                errorElement: 'span',

                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).parents ('.control-group').removeClass ('success').addClass('error');
                },
                success: function(element) {
                    $(element).parents ('.control-group').removeClass ('error').addClass('success');
                    $(element).parents ('.controls:not(:has(.clean))').find ('div:last').before ('<div class="clean"></div>');
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parents ('.controls'));
                },
                   submitHandler: function() {

                       alert("hello");

                       var name = $('#name').val();
                       var description = $('#description').val();
                       var accessKey = $('#accessKey').val();
                       var secretKey = $('#secretKey').val();

                        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&description=' + description + '&accessKey=' + accessKey+ '&secretKey=' + secretKey;
                        //alert(dataString);

                        $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "/demo/save",
                          data: dataString,
                          success: function(data) {
                            $('#result').html("<h2>demo created successfully!</h2>");
                           },
                            error: function(data) {
                                $("#result").html("<h2>Error!</h2>");
                            }
                        }) 

                    }
        });
     });
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NJxh5/3/
Thank you

Comment: please find the jsfiddle link here : http://jsfiddle.net/NJxh5/3/

Answer (score 6):

`.validate()` is the method for *initializing* the plugin.  It's not a method of testing the form.  Testing is automatic.

Therefore, get rid of the `click` handler.  The click event is captured automatically by the plugin.  If the form is valid, the `submitHandler` will fire.

Otherwise, you are doing it properly by placing your `ajax` inside the `submitHandler` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#projectForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // rules & options
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // ajax method
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ACdtX/**

---

With two different buttons and actions:

HTML:

```
<form id="projectForm">
    ....
    <input type="button" class="button" value="TEST" id="test" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Create" id="create" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.button').each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            var action;
            if ($(this).attr('id') == "test") {
                action = 'test.php';
            } else {
                action = 'create.php';
            }
            $('#projectForm').submit();
        });
    });

    $('#projectForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // rules & options
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // ajax method
            $.ajax({
                url: action, // determined from click handler above
                // ajax options
            });      
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I have two submit buttons in my form, test and create. Test needs to call a separate method and Create needs to create a separate JS method , both of these perform separate functionality. So I have the click handlers.

Comment: @SanthoshS, I understand.  But `.validate()` cannot be used inside of a `click` handler.  It's **not** the testing method of the form so calling it from a different click handler will do nothing.  `validate()` is how you _initialize_ the plugin on the form.  After initialization, subsequent calls to `.validate()` are meaningless.

Comment: @SanthoshS, See my other answer over here to learn how to do something like you describe:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228546/594235